# Mysql Query Check New

Tags: mysql

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Employee` (
  `SSN` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  `Name` varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Designation` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
  `MSSN` varchar(64) NOT NULL, 
  PRIMARY KEY (`SSN`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_Manager_Employee`  
              FOREIGN KEY (`MSSN`) REFERENCES Employee(SSN)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

INSERT INTO Employee VALUES 
 ("1", "A", "OWNER",  "1"),  

 ("2", "B", "BOSS",   "1"), # Employees under OWNER 
 ("3", "F", "BOSS",   "1"),

 ("4", "C", "BOSS",   "2"), # Employees under B
 ("5", "H", "BOSS",   "2"), 
 ("6", "L", "WORKER", "2"), 
 ("7", "I", "BOSS",   "2"), 
 # Remaining Leaf nodes   
 ("8", "K", "WORKER", "3"), # Employee under F     

 ("9", "J", "WORKER", "7"), # Employee under I     

 ("10","G", "WORKER", "5"), # Employee under H

 ("11","D", "WORKER", "4"), # Employee under C
 ("12","E", "WORKER", "4")  ;

SELECT  SUPERVISOR.name AS SuperVisor, 
        GROUP_CONCAT(SUPERVISEE.name  ORDER BY SUPERVISEE.name ) AS SuperVisee, 
        COUNT(*)  
FROM Employee AS SUPERVISOR 
  INNER JOIN Employee SUPERVISEE ON  SUPERVISOR.SSN = SUPERVISEE.MSSN 
GROUP BY SuperVisor;
```

Comment: please add some details to the question

Comment: result is:  no rows selected. why?

Comment: @sumit it is problem of group by. Group to one column...

Comment: It works: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c263c/1

Answer (score 0):

See this:

```
SELECT  SUPERVISOR.name AS SuperVisor, 
        GROUP_CONCAT(SUPERVISEE.name  ORDER BY SUPERVISEE.name ) AS SuperVisee, 
        COUNT(*)  
FROM Employee AS SUPERVISOR 
  INNER JOIN Employee SUPERVISEE ON  SUPERVISOR.SSN = SUPERVISEE.MSSN 
GROUP BY SuperVisor;
```

Result:

```
+------------+------------+----------+
| SuperVisor | SuperVisee | COUNT(*) |
+------------+------------+----------+
|
| C          | D,E        |        2 |
| F          | K          |        1 |
| H          | G          |        1 |
| I          | J          |        1 |
+------------+------------+----------+
```

Comment: Please explain what you changed. It looks the same to me.